# akquinet (Android with test archetype) - unit tests are not executed

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I've generated an Android project using the [akquinet](http://stand.spree.de/wiki_details_maven_archetypes) archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=android-with-test \
-DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.11 \
-DgroupId=com.foo.bar \
-DartifactId=my-android-project \
-Dpackage=com.foo.bar.android
```

This archetype creates

1. a parent project,
2. `myproject` project with the actual Android application and
3. `myproject-it` with the integration tests.

When I add the following test class into the `myproject-it` project and run `mvn install`, I don't get a test failure message.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimCardReaderTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetAvailableSimCards()
    {
        Assert.fail("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

Hence, the unit test is not executed.

What can I do in order to run unit tests (tests, which do not depend on the Android environment) in a project based on akquinet?

Comment: I would prefer put POJO JUnit test in application project's src/test/java folder, not application test project's src/main/java folder.

Comment: @yorkw That's what I did. But in order for this solution to work, I needed to manually adapt Eclipse's project files, which is not elegant and prone to error.

Comment: Check out answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593842/simple-non-api-android-junit-test-in-eclipse-with-android-maven-plugin/17136833#17136833) to see how to configure and run POJO JUnit test in Eclipse. Note that it doesn't requires any extra step if you run `mvn test` from command-line.

Comment: @yorkw The problem was that Eclipse didn't recognize `myproject/src/test/java` as a source folder.

Comment: @yorkw You may submit your answer (place unit tests into the `myproject` test folder) and I'll accept it (provided that there are no better answers).

Comment: The latest M2E plugin should automatically add `src/test/java` as source folder when you create or import project, regardless of whether it actually exist in file system. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976223/how-to-deal-with-missing-src-test-java-source-folder-in-android-maven-project/11978134#11978134) for more details.