# Is there a way to use d3.js in swt composite

Tags: javascript, java

I am working on an eclipse plug-in where in I need some kind of data visualization. I find d3's visualization to be very useful. Since d3 is a javascript library, the charts can be displayed in browser. But I want the charts to display on swt composite.

Is there any way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SWT browser widget. By default it is linked to IE DLL on windows and XULrunner DLL on linux.

Comment: Using swt browser will basically make it a web based application which will require some kind of web server. But I want it  to be standalone.

Comment: No. The SWT browser can load stuff from local file. There is absolutely no need for a web server.

Comment: But I wanted the visualization on some kind of frame or panel so that i can have more control over the UI. For example if the user clicks on some thing on the UI a java method should be triggered in the pulg-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javafx-d3](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3)
 to interact with d3.js in a JavaFx WebView (which should be able to be integrated in SWT).

### How I got a minimal example to run:

First, install javafx-d3 as explained on the github page:

> - Get the source code
> - You can use the main folder as an Eclipse workspace including two projects:
> - Import the two Eclipse Maven projects javafx-d3 and javafx-d3-demo
> - Build the maven projects
> - Run the demo suite `com.github.javafxd3.d3.JavaFxD3DemoSuite`
> - If you do not get javafx-d3 up and running please create an issue ticket.

(Working in Eclipse I had to solve the problem of a [missing 'src/test/java' folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976223/how-to-deal-with-missing-src-test-java-source-folder-in-android-maven-project) on the way.)

Next I followed this [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-javafx-20-swing) to integrate the `browser` from the `JavaFxSingleDemo` into an SWT shell. 
(I had to manually import  the javafx.embed.swt package - see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841798/javafx-package-javafx-embed-swt-not-in-java8u5))

```
public class SwtIntegrationDemo {

    private static Scene scene;
    private static JavaFxD3Browser browser;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("JavaFX / SWT Integration");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        final FXCanvas canvas = new FXCanvas(shell, SWT.NONE);        

        //define d3 content as post loading hook
        final Runnable postLoadingHook = () -> {
            System.out.println("Initial loading of browser is finished");
            //do some d3 stuff
            createD3Example();        };

        //create browser
        browser = new JavaFxD3Browser(postLoadingHook, true);

        //create the scene
        scene = new Scene(browser, 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        canvas.setScene(scene);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();    
    }

    private static void createD3Example() {
        // code from JavaFxD3SingleDemo.java
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide details that show how to achieve the OP's question.